# File explorer first instance hangs, second runs OK

Tags: file, search, instance, freeze, explorer

Very often, when I open File Explorer (on Windows 10) it "hangs", showing empty panels with a search bar on the top slowly moving to the right, with nothing else happening. However, if I open a second (or third, etc....) instance of the same file explorer, it immmediately works showing all the files (while the first keeps on "searching" with no results). If I close everything and re-open the Explorer, once again the first instance hangs on this sort of search activity, while the second works OK.

Unfortunately this behaviour is a bit random (see the "very often" above). I have tried closing any other program that might interfere, but couldn't find anything. I also couldn't find much help by googling it. My guess is that by using the PC at some point I run some program that corrupts something ...

Any hint on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem for the umpteenth time, and I definitely found the fix for this iteration. After trying several things, this was the instantaneous fix for the slow scanning bar and slow column sorting:

1. Navigate to the problem folder in the Window Explorer folder view.
2. Right-click the folder and select "Properties".
3. In Properties, select the "Customize" tab.
4. Make sure "Optimize this folder for:" is set to "General Items" AND "Also apply this template to all subfolders" is checked.
5. Click OK.

This immediately brought my problem folders to life and everything worked normally. I would recommend doing this at the Drive level folder, and then go back and customize folder such as Pictures, Music, and Videos. The [reference that solved the issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/explorer-sort-by-date-very-very-slow/11dde6fa-3571-4e6f-b09d-813ee907820e) is quite old, but still seems to be an issue (and the fix).

Before this I had tried rebooting several times, cleaning out shortcuts, sfc, dsim, and several other things that did not have any effect. Now opening any folder is lightning fast with no scan and sorting by name, type, size, or date modified is just as quick.